# user-defined exception for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I want to implement my own exception to handle if the user is looking for a value in an array which does not exist or to access an undefined index in the array.

```
int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3};
myIntArray[4] = ?? // this invoke ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

So what I really want to do is like this:

```
  try{
     System.out.println("Access element:" + a[4]);
  }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
     // call my own exception witch I create in a new class
  }
```

Some how like this:

```
public class myException extends Exception
{
   public invalideIndexException()
   {

   } 
}
```

I'm new in programming, the Java doc was helpful, but I'm still confused by achieving this.

Comment: You could do `throw new MyException();` within the `catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
try{
     System.out.println("Access element:" + a[4]);
  }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
     throw new CustomArrayIndexOutOfBoundException("blah blah"); // here
  }
```

Throw your own exception after catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
class CustomArrayIndexOutOfBoundException extends Exception{  
 CustomArrayIndexOutOfBoundException(String s){  
  super(s);  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write a message inside CustomArrayIndexOutOfBoundException("-------");

Comment: Last question, is it possible to put more than one exception in CustomArrayIndexOutOfBoundException class to handle exceptions like element the user is looking for does not exist and invalid index.

Comment: @CyberAllien Nope only one exception. "The index you are looking for is does not exist or invalid". But if you want to really check it is invalid, you can check the validity of index with an if condition and you can throw from there.

Comment: I want to throw exception when the element is not found and the index is not valid.

Comment: @CyberAllien What is invalid you mean ? you can check it right /

Comment: Example, in my array{1,2,3,4} I do this array[5](throw exception) and I look for element 10 and it's not in the array(throw exception)

Comment: Both leads to  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.